# React Table Increment Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React, and I'm trying to make a table using react that displays information about a car. Currently, I'm trying to implement two buttons on each row that would increment/decrement a certain field of the table.

This is the code for the table:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                {                    
                    this.state.cars.map(car =>                         
                        <tr key={car.model}>
                            <td>{car.manufacturer}</td>
                            <td>{car.model}</td>
                            <td>{car.year}</td>
                            <td>{car.stock}</td>
                            <td>${car.price}</td>
                            <td><button type="button" onClick={this.increaseStock.bind(this)}>Increment</button></td>
                            <td><button type="button" onClick={this.decreaseStock.bind(this)}>Decrement</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    ))                    
                }
            </table>
        );
    };
```

This so far is just fine for displaying the data and buttons, however, I'm not actually sure how to implement the buttons' functions

All the implementations for `increaseStock` and `decreaseStock` so far have done nothing on click, although I think they're being called. I'm trying to get it to either add to the stock value or subtract from it(not going below 0).

I've tried things using states, but I'm not really sure how those work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how your component could be implemented. I used the functional component and a state hook because those are what I'm familiar with.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function CarTable() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Car 1", stock: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Car 2", stock: 10 }
  ]);

  const increase = (index) => {
    const oldCar = cars[index];
    // copying the car with the updated stock
    const newCar = { ...oldCar, stock: oldCar.stock + 1 };
    //copying the car array
    const newCars = [...cars];
    //replacing the old car with a new one in a new array
    newCars[index] = newCar;
    //updating state
    setCars(newCars);
  };

  const decrease = (index) => {
    // same as above except decreasing the stock now
    const oldCar = cars[index];
    const newCar = { ...oldCar, stock: oldCar.stock - 1 };
    const newCars = [...cars];
    newCars[index] = newCar;
    setCars(newCars);
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>stock</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {cars.map((car, i) => (
          <tr key={car.id}>
            <td>{car.name}</td>
            <td>{car.stock}</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={() => increase(i)}>increase</button>
              <button onClick={() => decrease(i)}>decrease</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

In short what you need to do is create a new `car` object with the updated `stock` property. Then create a new `cars` array with the new `car` object just mentioned and then set the state to this new `cars` array.

Here's also a CodeSandbox link where you can try it out:

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dijkstra-8brqz1?file=/src/CarTable.js

Hope that helps.

Comment: Links can expire. Please use code blocks as well as or instead of a codesandbox. Using a code block is also better for search results.

Comment: @ethry done. Hope that's better